# mongodb server is not starting, mac os

Tags: mongodb, macos, macos-sierra

When running:

```
mongod
```

I get:

```
2017-04-30T11:19:56.234+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1160 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Interstellar

2017-04-30T11:19:56.234+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.4

2017-04-30T11:19:56.234+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 888390515874a9debd1b6c5d36559ca86b44babd

2017-04-30T11:19:56.234+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

2017-04-30T11:19:56.234+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system

2017-04-30T11:19:56.234+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none

2017-04-30T11:19:56.234+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:

2017-04-30T11:19:56.235+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64

2017-04-30T11:19:56.235+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64

2017-04-30T11:19:56.235+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}

2017-04-30T11:19:56.235+0600 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in 
initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating

2017-04-30T11:19:56.235+0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...

2017-04-30T11:19:56.235+0600 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...

2017-04-30T11:19:56.235+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting

2017-04-30T11:19:56.235+0600 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I'm having trouble with this, badly need help

Comment: The answer given is perfect. Just want to add that you can change the default DB directories by way of the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you run "mongod" the default path is /usr/data. NEVERTHELESS macOS Catalina does not accept creating a writable folder there. So after long research, in both here, and reddit, I finally got my server (mongod as well as Mongo) up and running. Try the following these steps:

```
mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db

sudo chown -Rv <your_user_name> /System/Volumes/Data/data/db

sudo mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

This may run mongod and start the server. Open another terminal tab, and type Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

**First step**

```
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.4
```

**Second step**

```
cd /Users
whoami
cd to your whoami directory 
mkdir data
cd data
mkdir db
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

**Third step**

```
mongo
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that there is no /data/db directory.  Please issue this command:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

If you're not worried about opening up permissions too widely, but just want to ensure that mongodb has permissions to start, you can also issue these commands.  They may fix any problems you have if the above command alone doesn't solve things.

```
cd /
sudo chmod -R 777 data
```

Comment: macOS imposes restrictions on certain system folders. /data/db being one of those. You can't just  simply create a folder in there.